# how do I write this in XeTeX?

Tags: symbols

How do I write this $C$ below; it is almost $\cal C$ but a bit different.

[image]

Comment: That is just the Cal C, but the look of course depends on the chosen font.

Comment: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/

Comment: So I cannot type exactly this $C$ without some weird font, right ? BTW, what font shall I use and how can I make other $\cal C$ unchanged ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no "weird font": this is Euler script. It can be used for instance with the package [`eucal`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts), as in the following example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eucal}
\begin{document}
\( \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}_{cf} \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}_f \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C} \)
\end{document}
```

It can also be loaded with the option `cal=euler` of the package [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), as in the following example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\( \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}_{cf} \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}_f \to \operatorname{Ho} \mathcal{C}. \)
\end{document}
```

Both examples give the following output.
[image]

Comment: OK. Is there a way to compile your 2 scripts above with `mathjax` ?

Comment: @user2925716 Not that I know of, but I don't really know MathJax.